# Find largest 5 value less than 1, lowest 5 values

Tags: r

I have a large correlation matrix result in R - for now about 30 items correlated against each other - so the array has about 10,000 cells. I want to find the largest 5 and smallest 5 results. How can I do this?

Here's what a very small portion - the upper left corner - looks like:

```
               PL1         V3          V4         V5
PL1     1.00000000 0.19905701 -0.02994034 -0.1533846
V3      0.19905701 1.00000000  0.09036472  0.1306054
V4     -0.02994034 0.09036472  1.00000000  0.1848030
V5     -0.15338465 0.13060539  0.18480296  1.0000000
```

The values in the table are always between 1 & -1 and if it helps, being a correlation matrix the upper half above the diagonal is a duplicate of the lower half below the diagonal.

I need the most positive 5 less than 1 and the most negative 5 including -1 if it exists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find the largest and smallest correlations and probably know not only what, but where those values came from.  It's easy.

```
x<-matrix(runif(25),5,5)
cor<-cor(x)
l <- length(cor)
l1 <- length(cor[cor<1])

#the actual high and low correlation indexes 
corHigh <- order(cor)[(l1-4):l1]
corLow <- order(cor)[1:5]
#(if you just want to view the correlations cor[corLow] or cor[corHigh] works fine)

#isolate them in the matrix so you can see where they came from easily
corHighView <- cor
corHighView[!1:l %in% corHigh] <- NA
corLowView <- cor
corLowView[!1:l %in% corLow] <- NA

#look at your matrix with your target correlations sticking out like a sore thumb
corLowView
corHighView
```

Comment: I _really_ liked this solution visually. I added options(digits=2) just to make it more readable. I do note that for some reason it routinely drops the last solution from either the top or bottom of the final viewing array, but not both, so you can still see it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you liked it... I'm not sure what you mean.  I will say that there are a few alternative ways of doing this that you might want to look into.  For example, if I used the corHigh index and retrieved the high value, and then in the assignment of NA's below checked to see !cor %in% highValues that would insure I could see duplicates, so you'd get 5 or more values back.  That may actually be your issue or even more what you want.  On the other hand, it will also show more than 5 values even if all the duplicates are in the very highest position so that's a judgment call on your part.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another crude way to do this (no doubt there is a much easier way), but it's not too hard to wrap this in a function:

EDIT: Shortened the code.

```
 # Simulate correlation matrix (taken from Patrick's answer)
set.seed(1)
n<-100
x<-matrix(runif(n^2),n,n)
cor<-cor(x)

# Set diagonal and one triangle to to 0:
diag(cor) <- 0
cor[upper.tri(cor)] <- 0

# Get sorted values:
sort <- sort(cor)

# Create a dummy matrix and get lowest 5:
min <- matrix(cor %in% sort[1:5] ,n,n)
which(min,arr.ind=T)

# Same for highest 5:
max <- matrix(cor %in% sort[(n^2-5):(n^2)] ,n,n)
which(max,arr.ind=T)
```

Another option, as ulidtko sayed, is to make a graph. You could try my package, called `qgraph`, which can be used to visualize a correlation matrix as a network:

```
library(qgraph)
qgraph(cor(x),vsize=2,minimum=0.2,filetype="png")
```

[image: qgraph output in PNG format]

Answer (score 2):

Interesting network graph Sacha. Here it is with real data. Seems I have much stronger positive than negative correlations.

[image]

Comment: That's quite common in real data, since data is usually about a general construct or so. You can make a png like my pic with the argument `filetype="png"` or a pdf with `filetype="pdf"`

Comment: +1 for the follow up (you could have incorporated it in your original answer).

Answer (score 1):

kind of dirty:

```
x<-matrix(runif(25),5,5)
cor<-cor(x)
max1<-max(cor)
max2<-max(cor[cor!=max1])
max3<-max(cor[cor!=max1 & cor!=max2])
max4<-max(cor[cor!=max1& cor!=max2& cor!=max3])
max5<-max(cor[cor!=max1& cor!=max2& cor!=max3& cor!=max4])
max6<-max(cor[cor!=max1& cor!=max2& cor!=max3& cor!=max4& cor!=max5])
maxes<-c(max2,max3,max4,max5,max6)
maxes
matrix(cor %in% maxes,5,5)
```

Comment: Could be put into a recursive look I think, but I agree. It's sort of rough. Does work though and the final matrix TRUE/FALSE output is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

How about a nice creamy plot? `:)`

```
> m <- matrix(runif(100)*2-1, ncol=10)
> colnames(m) <- rownames(m) <- paste("V", 1:10, sep="")
> m
             V1          V2         V3         V4         V5         V6           V7           V8         V9         V10
V1  -0.40101571 -0.27049070  0.2414295 -0.1889384  0.6459941 -0.8851884  0.332284597 -0.431312791  0.3828374  0.46398193
V2   0.38557771  0.37083911 -0.3004923  0.1253908 -0.4405188 -0.5424613  0.869493425  0.023291914  0.9625392 -0.83196773
V3   0.61923503 -0.27615909  0.1759168 -0.7333568 -0.4256801 -0.6170807  0.438613391 -0.003632086  0.4113488 -0.40590330
V4   0.72093123  0.68479573  0.5032486  0.3720876 -0.6775834  0.2445693  0.353658359 -0.839104640 -0.8122970 -0.42322187
V5  -0.08640529  0.04432795 -0.5120129 -0.9327905 -0.5821378  0.4671473 -0.367677007  0.483375219 -0.7849003  0.57686729
V6  -0.72451704  0.75814550  0.7838393 -0.7650238  0.6742669  0.2260757  0.001645839  0.570753074  0.1944579  0.07917656
V7   0.64516271  0.51994540  0.9057388 -0.3976167 -0.7403159 -0.2873382 -0.809354444  0.319095368 -0.9766422 -0.71981321
V8  -0.51509049  0.18727837 -0.1971454 -0.4290346  0.5657622  0.5324266  0.451608266 -0.715594335 -0.2749510  0.38234855
V9   0.49035803  0.50252397  0.7736783  0.3342899 -0.2732427  0.1128947  0.870315070 -0.291482237  0.5171181 -0.59784449
V10 -0.51811224 -0.67159723  0.8903813 -0.7562222 -0.9790557 -0.5830560 -0.715136643  0.167987391 -0.0529399  0.44570592

> library(ggplot2)
> p <- ggplot(data=melt(m), aes(x=X1, y=X2, color=value))
> p + geom_point(size=5, alpha=0.7) + scale_color_gradient2()
```

[image: the plot]

I don't think it would be hard to look at 100x100 plot and find extreme values with an eye. `:)`

Comment: The plot is quite nice. I agree that it's to all that difficult to pick out ones with stronger color.I suspect I'll have to take the diagonal which is all 1's in the real array but not in yours, and just set them to 0 or something. I notice that the ordering isn't the same as the matrix itself - it has V10 out of matrix order. Is there an option you can see to keep them in order?

Comment: BTW - melt was a nice choice. Maybe the melt results could just be sorted to return the highest and lowest 5?

Answer (score 0):

I take no credit for this, just posting the code in case [the link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-February/188225.html) dies... Credit to Dimitris on the r-help list. It returns a list of *p* top correlations involving each variable, sorted.

```
cor.mat <- cor(matrix(rnorm(100*1000), 1000, 100)) 
p <- 30 # how many top items
n <- ncol(cor.mat)
cmat <- col(cor.mat)
ind <- order(-cmat, cor.mat, decreasing = TRUE) - (n * cmat - n)
dim(ind) <- dim(cor.mat)
ind <- ind[seq(2, p + 1), ]
out <- cbind(ID = c(col(ind)), ID2 = c(ind)) 
as.data.frame(cbind(out,cor = cor.mat[out]))
```